# how to track down my custom module issue?it throw out error

Tags: magento2, customer, newsletter-subscriber

how do I track where the problem of my custom module.
I got below error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ABC\NewsletterCrm\Controller\Subscriber\Confirm\Interceptor::loadByCustomerId() in /app/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php:105 Stack trace:  
#0 /app/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php(120): Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info->getSubscriptionObject()
#1 /app/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml(39): Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info->getIsSubscribed() 
#2 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/app/vendor/mag...') 
#3 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info), '/app/vendor/mag...', Array) 
#4 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/app/vendor/mag...')
#5 /app/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard in /app/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php on line 105
```

I wrote a override module at app\code\ABC\NewsletterCrm\Controller\Subscriber\Confirm.php
using Object Manager to getCustomerID, please help

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subscribeCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber');
$collection = $subscribeCollection->getCollection()
                                  ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_id', $id);

foreach ($collection as $subscribe){


    $customerid = $subscribe->getCustomerId();  

}
```

Comment: should be better if u pastle whole class You wrote, and part from di.xml where you set override. And explain what You wanted to do

Comment: Oh! you right, I had mistake with my di.xml. Thanks! its work now